# How to replace negative numbers in Pandas Data Frame by zero

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, negative-number

I would like to know if there is someway of replacing all DataFrame negative numbers by zeros?

Comment: Also, I believe your second line should read `num[num < 0] = 0`

Answer (score 149, accepted):

If all your columns are numeric, you can use boolean indexing:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, -1, 2], 'b': [-3, 2, 1]})

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   a  b
0  0 -3
1 -1  2
2  2  1

In [4]: df[df < 0] = 0

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
   a  b
0  0  0
1  0  2
2  2  1
```

---

For the more general case, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12726468/1258041) shows the private method `_get_numeric_data`:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, -1, 2], 'b': [-3, 2, 1],
                           'c': ['foo', 'goo', 'bar']})

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   a  b    c
0  0 -3  foo
1 -1  2  goo
2  2  1  bar

In [4]: num = df._get_numeric_data()

In [5]: num[num < 0] = 0

In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
   a  b    c
0  0  0  foo
1  0  2  goo
2  2  1  bar
```

---

With `timedelta` type, boolean indexing seems to work on separate columns, but not on the whole dataframe. So you can do:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': pd.to_timedelta([0, -1, 2], 'd'),
   ...:                    'b': pd.to_timedelta([-3, 2, 1], 'd')})

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
        a       b
0  0 days -3 days
1 -1 days  2 days
2  2 days  1 days

In [4]: for k, v in df.iteritems():
   ...:     v[v < 0] = 0
   ...:     

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
       a      b
0 0 days 0 days
1 0 days 2 days
2 2 days 1 days
```

---

**Update:** comparison with a `pd.Timedelta` works on the whole DataFrame:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': pd.to_timedelta([0, -1, 2], 'd'),
   ...:                    'b': pd.to_timedelta([-3, 2, 1], 'd')})

In [3]: df[df < pd.Timedelta(0)] = 0

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
       a      b
0 0 days 0 days
1 0 days 2 days
2 2 days 1 days
```

Answer (score 143):

Another succinct way of doing this is [pandas.DataFrame.clip](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html).

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

In [20]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [-1, 100, -2]})

In [21]: df
Out[21]: 
     a
0   -1
1  100
2   -2

In [22]: df.clip(lower=0)
Out[22]: 
     a
0    0
1  100
2    0
```

Comment: This is the inline solution I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: If you only want to apply `clip` on a specific column you can go like `df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].clip(lower=0)`

Comment: `clip_lower` has been [deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip_lower.html) so rather stick to `df.clip(lower=0)`

Comment: This seems to be the fastest method

Comment: @DomingoR said this is inline, but this doesn't edit the values inplace, you need to assign to the same column to have the clip work.

Comment: @Diedre Inline is no the same as inplace.

Answer (score 21):

Another clean option that I have found useful is  [pandas.DataFrame.mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html#pandas.DataFrame.mask) which will "replace values where the condition is true."

Create the DataFrame:

```
In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, -1, 2], 'b': [-3, 2, 1]})

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
   a  b
0  0 -3
1 -1  2
2  2  1
```

Replace negative numbers with 0:

```
In [5]: df.mask(df < 0, 0)
Out[5]: 
   a  b
0  0  0
1  0  2
2  2  1
```

Or, replace negative numbers with NaN, which I frequently need:

```
In [7]: df.mask(df < 0)
Out[7]: 
     a    b
0  0.0  NaN
1  NaN  2.0
2  2.0  1.0
```

Comment: `.mask()` is as KISS as it gets!

Answer (score 14):

Perhaps you could use `pandas.where(args)` like so:

```
data_frame = data_frame.where(data_frame < 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 14):

With lambda function

```
df['column'] = df['column'].apply(lambda x : x if x > 0 else 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are dealing with a large df (40m x 700 in my case) it works much faster and memory savvy through iteration on columns with something like.

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col][df[col] < 0] = 0
```

Comment: You get a *A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame* warning when you do this

Comment: Perhaps using .copy() will avoid it

Answer (score 1):

A slight modification of the answers present.

Let's identify all the numeric columns and create a dataframe with all numeric values.
Then replace the negative values with NaN in new dataframe

```
df_numeric = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])
df_numeric = df_numeric.where(lambda x: x > 0, np.nan)
```

Now, drop the columns where negative values are handled in the main data frame and then concatenate the new column values to the main data frame

```
numeric_cols = df_numeric.columns.values
df = df.drop(columns=numeric_cols)
df = pd.concat([df, df_numeric], axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dataset of mixed data types, also consider moving the non-numerics to the index, updating the data, then removing the index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, -1, 2], 'b': [-3, 2, 1],
                       'c': ['foo', 'goo', 'bar']})
df = df.set_index('c')
df[df < 0] = 0
df = df.reset_index()
```

The approach using `_get_numeric_data()` didn't work for me for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.loc[(df < 0).index, :] = 0
```

To avoid getting a unpredicatable behavior: [Returning a view versus a copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)