# Replace dataframe column negative values with nan, in method chain

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace by `np.nan` all the *negative* numbers that are in column  `'b'`

- using a method on df
- not in place.

Here's the sample frame:

```
pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2] , 'b': [-3, 4], 'c': [5, -6]})
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759084/how-to-replace-negative-numbers-in-pandas-data-frame-by-zero) for in-place and non-method solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `assign` counts as a method on df, you can recalculate the column `b` and assign it to `df` to replace the old column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2] , 'b': [-3, 4], 'c': [5, -6]})

df.assign(b = df.b.where(df.b.ge(0)))
#   a    b  c
#0  1  NaN  5
#1  2  4.0 -6
```

For better chaining behavior, you can use `lambda` function with `assign`:

```
df.assign(b = lambda x: x.b.where(x.b.ge(0)))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **loc** function.To replace the all the negative values and leverage numpy nan to replace them.
sample code look like.

```
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2] , 'b': [-3, 4], 'c': [5, -6]})
df.loc[~(df['b'] > 0), 'b']=np.nan
```