# Replace values in specified list of columns based on a condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The actual use case is that I want to replace all of the values in some named columns with zero whenever they are less than zero, but leave other columns alone. Let's say in the dataframe below, I want to floor all of the values in column `a` and `b` to zero, but leave column `d` alone.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, -1, 2], 'b': [-3, 2, 1],
                       'c': ['foo', 'goo', 'bar'], 'd' : [1,-2,1]})
df 
   a  b    c  d
0  0 -3  foo  1
1 -1  2  goo -2
2  2  1  bar  1
```

The second paragraph in the accepted answer to this question: [How to replace negative numbers in Pandas Data Frame by zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759084/how-to-replace-negative-numbers-in-pandas-data-frame-by-zero) does provide a workaround, I can just set the datatype of column `d` to be non-numeric, and then change it back again afterwards:

```
df['d'] = df['d'].astype(object)
num = df._get_numeric_data()
num[num <0] = 0
df['d'] = df['d'].astype('int64')
df
   a  b    c  d
0  0  0  foo  1
1  0  2  goo -2
2  2  1  bar  1
```

but this seems really messy, and it means I need to know the list of the columns I don't want to change, rather than the list I do want to change.

Is there a way to just specify the column names directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mask` and column filtering:

```
df[['a','b']] = df[['a','b']].mask(df<0, 0)
df
```

Output

```
   a  b    c  d
0  0  0  foo  1
1  0  2  goo -2
2  2  1  bar  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `np.where`

```
cols_to_change = ['a', 'b', 'd']

df.loc[:, cols_to_change] = np.where(df[cols_to_change]<0, 0, df[cols_to_change])

    a   b   c   d
0   0   0   foo 1
1   0   2   goo 0
2   2   1   bar 1
```