# How to replace zeros in Pandas Data Frame by negative 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Replacing negative numbers to zero is straightforward, see
[How to replace negative numbers in Pandas Data Frame by zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759084/how-to-replace-negative-numbers-in-pandas-data-frame-by-zero) but I want to know how to do the opposite.

I want to replace the 0 here to -1:

[image]

But `df.replace(0,-1)` or `df[df == 0] = -1` gives me

[image]

It seems like I am able to replace the zeros into positive integers but I cannot replace them with negative integers (i.e. `df.replace(0,-3)` replaces all my zeros with -253).

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you sure your columns have type ```int```, and not ```str``` or ```bool```?

Comment: What is the output of `df.dtypes`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have a data type of 8 bit unsigned integer.  For that data type, there are no negatives and therefore a `-1` overflows(underflows?) to the largest such number.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1], [1, 0]], dtype=np.uint8)

df.replace(0, -1)

     0    1
0  255    1
1    1  255
```

Where `255` is the largest such number.

```
np.iinfo(np.uint8).max

255
```

Instead, set the data type first

```
df.astype(int).replace(0, -1)

   0  1
0 -1  1
1  1 -1
```