# Replace Negative values with Null in pandas column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My `duration` column in dataframe contains negative timedelta values as shown below:

```
NaT
00:27:03.466021
-1 days +23:57:26.139011
00:10:06.227683
```

How to replace negative dates to Null or NaT in dataframe column?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace negative numbers in Pandas Data Frame by zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759084/how-to-replace-negative-numbers-in-pandas-data-frame-by-zero)

Answer (score 0):

Use below command

```
mask=df['duration'] < pd.Timedelta(0)
df['duration'].mask(mask)
```