# Converting negative values in dataframe to NaN

Tags: python, dataframe, replace, nan

I have a dataframe that has negative values. I would like to replace the negative values to NaN.
The dataframe contains different column types (Object, float, int..) and has over 15 numeric columns so I am looking for a solution that would identify the numeric columns then change the negative values to NaN.

```
name                sodium   potass    .....
Natural Bran         130      280      .....
All-Bran             -1       330      .....
Almond Delight      200       -5       .....
Tex                 120       -2       .....
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Using [`pandas.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) could solve your problem.

```
df = df.mask(df < 0) # default replaced value is nan when the condition is fulfilled.
```

To only apply it on numeric columns, we can select those columns by checking their `dtypes`.

```
df.select_dtypes(include=np.number)
np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number)
```

So the final solution is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [-1, 3, 4], "b": [3.2, 2.3, -2.3], "c": ["a", "b", "c"]})
df2 = df.apply(lambda x: x.apply(lambda y: np.nan if y < 0 else y) if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number) else x)
print(df2)
```

output:

```
     a    b  c
0  NaN  3.2  a
1  3.0  2.3  b
2  4.0  NaN  c
```

Comment: See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759084/how-to-replace-negative-numbers-in-pandas-data-frame-by-zero) for more solutions

Comment: Hello! thanks for your help. I initially tried the above code and df[df < 0] = np.nan. However, I get the following error: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'    . Is there a way to only look at numeric columns?

Comment: @user11427018 have updated the answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This also works

```
import numpy as np

df[df < 0] = np.nan
```

if you want to make changes in particular cols

```
df[df['sodium'] < 0] = np.nan
```

Comment: When I apply this code, the entire row where there is a negative value changes to nan. Is there a way to avoid that?