# How to replace negative numbers in Data Frame with contain other data types as well to by zero

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find a solution to replace the negative numbers in a data frame to 0, there are a few suggestions in stack over flow ([How to replace negative numbers in Pandas Data Frame by zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759084/how-to-replace-negative-numbers-in-pandas-data-frame-by-zero)). But most of them work under the assumption that there is only one data type in the data frame, like float and so it doesnt work when there is a character and a date data type along with float.

Is it possible to just replace the columns which are float/numeric and ignore the date type and replace the values which are lesser than 0 to 0?

Any suggestions?

The data frame I am working with is given below:

```
{'ds': {'XYZ-100742': Timestamp('2023-01-01 00:00:00')}, 'X1': {'XYZ-100742': 101.0}, 'X2': {'XYZ-100742': 35.0}, 'X3': {'XYZ-100742': 33.0}, 'X4': {'XYZ-100742': 100.0}, 'X5': {'XYZ-100742': 101.0}, 'X6': {'XYZ-100742': 94.0}, 'X7': {'XYZ-100742': 116.0}, 'X8': {'XYZ-100742': 129.0}, 'X9': {'XYZ-100742': 108.0}, 'X10': {'XYZ-100742': -82.0}, 'X11': {'XYZ-100742': 47.0}, 'X12': {'XYZ-100742': 150.0}, 'X13': {'XYZ-100742': 129.0}, 'X14': {'XYZ-100742': 84.0}, 'X15': {'XYZ-100742': 48.0}, 'X16': {'XYZ-100742': -62.0}, 'X17': {'XYZ-100742': 150.0}, 'X18': {'XYZ-100742': -9.0}}
```

The Code which I wrote to solve this issue is given below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel ('C:/X/X/X/Book1.xlsx')
df[df<0]=0
```

This runs into an error. Which I am assuming is because of the different data types in the data frame. Attached is the error:

```
**TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'**
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html) with [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) for numeric columns:

```
cols = df.select_dtypes(np.number).columns
df[cols] = df[cols].clip(lower=0)
```

Alternative:

```
df.update(df.select_dtypes(np.number).clip(lower=0))
```

Or use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
cols = df.select_dtypes(np.number).columns
df[cols] = df[cols].mask(df[cols] < 0, 0)
```

EDIT:

```
Timestamp = pd.Timestamp
d = {'ds': {'XYZ-100742': Timestamp('2023-01-01 00:00:00')}, 'X1': {'XYZ-100742': 101.0}, 'X2': {'XYZ-100742': 35.0}, 'X3': {'XYZ-100742': 33.0}, 'X4': {'XYZ-100742': 100.0}, 'X5': {'XYZ-100742': 101.0}, 'X6': {'XYZ-100742': 94.0}, 'X7': {'XYZ-100742': 116.0}, 'X8': {'XYZ-100742': 129.0}, 'X9': {'XYZ-100742': 108.0}, 'X10': {'XYZ-100742': -82.0}, 'X11': {'XYZ-100742': 47.0}, 'X12': {'XYZ-100742': 150.0}, 'X13': {'XYZ-100742': 129.0}, 'X14': {'XYZ-100742': 84.0}, 'X15': {'XYZ-100742': 48.0}, 'X16': {'XYZ-100742': -62.0}, 'X17': {'XYZ-100742': 150.0}, 'X18': {'XYZ-100742': -9.0}}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)


cols = df.select_dtypes(np.number).columns
df[cols] = df[cols].clip(lower=0)
print (df)
                   ds     X1    X2    X3     X4     X5    X6     X7     X8  \
XYZ-100742 2023-01-01  101.0  35.0  33.0  100.0  101.0  94.0  116.0  129.0   

               X9  X10   X11    X12    X13   X14   X15  X16    X17  X18  
XYZ-100742  108.0  0.0  47.0  150.0  129.0  84.0  48.0  0.0  150.0  0.0
```

Comment: This isnt working. I am not sure why maybe because of the data set. I changed the data set to get an exact replica. Could you please have a look with this data set. Apologies if it was from my side.

Comment: @user20203146 - Can you check? My answer was edited by your data.